# What are security settings on Sitecore language items for?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm familiar with using Language Read and Language Write to control access to language versions of items (set on system/languages/whicheverlanguage) but what do the actual Read/Write/Rename/Create/Delete/Administer permissions on a language item do? Are they settings for the language item itself, or are they language settings for language versions of items in that language? In short, what's the difference between Write and Language Write on the language item?

Confused...

Crossposted to SDN
http://sdn.sitecore.net/forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=34566#34566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are language settings on a language versions of items in that language. "Write" on language definition item is "Write" exactly on that item. "Language Write" on language definition item is "write" on items' versions in this language.

BTW, [this is what can happen](http://sdn.sitecore.net/forum//ShowPost.aspx?PostID=12825) if a user from another domain does not have language:read (see my last post there; that thread takes Active Directory domain as an example, but it is common behavior for other custom domains).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but wasn't 100% sure. Good post on SDN there, btw.